# Setup two-way SSL on Nginx with upstream server

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have two independent systems interacting with each other with two-way SSL.

System A <---2 way ssl---> Third Party System

I have a use-case where the request needs to be forwarded to third-party system via Nginx. How to I avoid SSL handshake at Nginx and proxy it to the original systems or have handshake between Nginx and upstream (Third Party System).

System A <------>NGIXN<---2 WAY SSL--> Third Party System

or

System A <-----2 WAY SSL--- (proxy)NGIXN ---2 WAY SSL--> Third Party System

Comment: I would think the answer is you can't do this.  Why are you trying to have nginx in the path?

Comment: Possibly what you are looking for is a stream proxy?  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: @Zoredache The third party can whitelist limited IPs. Need to route all my requests through a common proxy.

Comment: @Zoredache its not a stream, these are https requests. I want either nginx to not interfere with the two way ssl handshake or do handshake between nginx and upstream.

Comment: Right, which is exactly what a 'stream' proxy should do.  It will listen for the TCP connect, and forward it. It will not do anything with http/https/tls stuff.  BTW, you could always just use any other simple TCP proxy.

Comment: @Zoredache Ohh, let me try it out. Will update you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has a module to arbritrary TCP/UDP proxy .

Your nginx binary must have compiled with option `--with-stream`

See
https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

See 
https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Nginx only plays a proxy role in your system, given the SSL mechanism of System A and Third Party System unchanged.

I suggest just using the IP forwarding mechanism built in Linux.
enable the ip forwarding of your middle machine;
add ip forwarding rule on its firewall, and masquerade source IP if needed.

Middle Machine has the IP allowed by Third Party.
And you tell that system A to connect to middle machine on a particular port 7777.
Middle Machine than forward local port 7777 to the Third Party ip:port with masquerade. The Third Party would see your middle machine connecting to it.